# Groovy: Is it possible to abandon the reserved word?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

With the upgrading of Groovy, i met a really annoying problem with the new added reserved word: `trait`.

Because before the upgrade, i implemented many many variables named `trait` and also Classes extended from the Trait Class i finished.

example code just like:

```
class Dataseries extends Trait {
    SingleTrait trait
    ...
    ...
}
```

it would take really a lot of time to rename all the names...

So i consider, if it is possible to abandon the reserved word which Groovy uses?

Comment: Maybe using [groovy `modify file in place`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+CLI) feature you could use to change the variable names

Comment: if you are (really really) desperate, you could roll your own groovy with the keyword removed.  but i guess an IDE with proper refactoring support will bring you far (before switching to the new groovy version).

Answer (score 3):

This was discussed when the feature was introduced

https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/pull/343#issuecomment-38570360

And as others have said, your two pragmatic options are:

1. Rename your variables
2. Stick with an old version of groovy (until then you do #1)

Comment: I like how jimwhite plays the devil advocate

Comment: it's now really difficult to choose a new name for the variable 'trait', what would be better according to the best practise of Java codestyle?

Answer (score 0):

> So i consider, if it is possible to abandon the reserved word which Groovy uses?

No, this is not possible.

Your classes named `Trait`, `SingleTrait` etc. will not need to be renamed, because they don't match `trait` case-sensitively.

Comment: yeah, not the class name, but many variables named trait, like `SingleTrait trait` will be detected as reserved word :(

Comment: you'll get an error at compile-time for those variables, and if you have a good IDE (e.g. IntelliJ), it shouldn't take more than 5 minutes to rename them

Comment: it's now really difficult to choose a new name for the variable 'trait', what would be better according to the best practise of Java codestyle?

Comment: @Demonbane I can't possibly answer that without knowing the code. You could call it something lame like `_trait` or `traitInstance`, but I'd choose something more meaningful, i.e. the variable name should describe the behaviour that is added by the trait, e.g. `flyingAbility`